# Recognize the distribution corresponding to this characteristic function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is given as $$\phi_X(t)=\frac{3+\cos(t)+\cos(2t)}{5}; $$ what is the distribution of $X$? I was thinking of the discrete random variable $X=0,1,2$ with mass $\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5}$ respectively, but it's not true. Is the distribution of $X$ related to this discrete random variable? Thanks

Comment: In complex exponential form you have $\phi(t) = \frac{3}{5} + \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it} + e^{2it} + e^{-2it}}{10}$. Does that help?

Comment: @Ian Thank you so much. It's still a discrete random variable, x=0,1,2,-1,-2

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to write the characteristic function as a linear combination of exponentials, that is, 
$$\phi_X(t)=\sum_{j= 1}^N p_j e^{i\theta_j t}     $$
then you have $\mathbb P (X=\theta_j)=p_j$ for each $j\in\{1,\dots,N\}$.

Using the formula in Ian's comment 
$$\phi_X(t) = \frac{3}{5} + \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it} + e^{2it} + e^{-2it}}{10},$$
we derive that $\mathbb P(X=0)=3/5$, 
$$\mathbb P(X=1)=\mathbb P(X=-1)=\mathbb P(X=2)=\mathbb P(X=-2)=\frac 1{10}. $$